# When choosing "Looks OK" in the "First answers" review queue, the wording implies we are obligated to vote

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, first-answers

The first option from the "First answers" review queue reads like this:

> **Looks OK**
> This answer is good as-is and not low quality (be sure to vote accordingly).

[image: screenhot]

The "be sure to vote accordingly" part confuses me a little bit — are we supposed to also upvote/downvote each of the answers that we review? And since we are choosing "Looks OK", I assume the natural action is upvoting. Is that what this wording is meant to imply?

Maybe we can replace the "be sure" phrasing with something less demanding, like "also consider"?

Comment: No, you're never obligated to do anything

Comment: I agree it should be changed. It should not imply that every answer passing the bar for the queue also deserves a vote, in either direction.

Comment: This is bad wording and most likely relevant network-wide. Maybe better to post on MSE (unless already posted of course, haven't checked yet)

Comment: Also the Other action option reads *"You have taken one or more actions on this __question__ and have finished your review"*

Comment: And for reference, the Looks OK option of the Late answers queue reads: *"Answer addresses the question, is unique, and is not low quality."* which seems more appropriate

Comment: I admit that I feel compelled by that instruction. To me it reads like: "You've judged this post as a worthy addition to the site, so you should upvote it."

Comment: When I review, this little note makes me use up all votes, unintentionally. :(

Comment: I've also felt somewhat compelled by that wording in the past. It may have caused me to hit skip on occasion when a post was good enough to leave alone but I didn't feel positive enough about it to upvote it.

Answer (score 7):

There are several places where the interface merely **reminds** you to vote. If you find a good post in the queue, it would be helpful to upvote it while you're there. Likewise, if the post is an attempt to answer, but isn't a good or useful answer, you should probably downvote it. Remember, the odds you go back later and do this are fairly low.

There is no obligation to vote.

Comment: I get what you're saying, and I agree with it in general, but I don't think this answers the question, and I don't think that the wording Christik is highlighting here is merely "reminding" one to vote. It seems to be an explicit instruction, and that violates what you yourself say about there being no obligation to vote. The wording should be changed. It is not reasonable to expect (or, in my opinion, even *remind*) users to upvote all posts that they review as "acceptable".